# Updated to 16.04 and there is no wifi option

Tags: wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

I am new to ubuntu and I just upgraded to 16.04 and the option to connect to a wifi network has disappeared. The following pictures explain it better

[image]

However when I click "Edit Connections..." I do see my wifi network here

[image]

from the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCXvEmRCobg) it says to check Software & updates >> Additional Drivers and it should show a Broadcom wireless driver that is not enabled, however when I navigate there I do not see any wireless drivers.  All I see is the following.

[image]

Also when I do `lspci -vnn | grep Network` I get
`3e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)` So I'm not even sure I should be looking for a Broadcom driver.

If someone could give me some advice as to how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126710/173693) fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless might not appear in Network Manager for several reasons. First, is the wireless turned off by the airplane mode button or wireless switch? Check, from the terminal:

```
rfkill list all
```

Is the wireless hard blocked? If so, find and press the button or switch.

The wireless might not appear in Network Manager because it is managed elsewhere; typically in the file /etc/network/interfaces. Check:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

Is your wireless interface, perhaps wlan0, listed? If you’d rather that Network Manager handle the wireless, amend the file to remove wlan0 or whatever the wireless interface is:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Change the file to read:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Save the changes to the file (Ctrl+o) and exit nano (Ctrl+x).

Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?