# No more WIFI. oem-wifi-intel-iwlwifi doesn't build on the new 4.4 kernel

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

i have trouble with internal wifi card on my Dell Latitude 5590 runing `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. 
What happend before problem occured:

1. I recieved notification that my laptop has updates, updated it, enrolled MOK (as it begged) and everything worked fine.
2. I decided to remove Code::Blocks, which resulted into [this](https://pastebin.com/sssXcxg9)
3. Restarted pc and Ubuntu lost embedded wifi adapter

`sudo lshw -C Network` shows

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
```

`lspci -nn` recognizes adapter

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: 
 Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
```

and `rfkill list` output is

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

As far as i understood the problem is in `oem-wifi-intel-iwlwifi-lp1757035-4.4-dkms-dkms`, because then i try to reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall oem-wifi-intel*`, it stops, signaling
`Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-143-generic`

Comment: Why don't you remove that `dkms` module completely and install HWE kernel?

Comment: How can i do that? Up to this moment i tried interfere OS as minimal as possible so as not to break anything :^)

Comment: This is related to https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/xenial/commit/?h=master-next&id=9c72ad08f1510332e9314046e6a2adba5064f39a

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 4.4 kernel doesn't support your wireless adapter. That is the reason you installed some dkms module with a backport of that driver.

After a kernel update the driver doesn't build, or is blocked by Secure Boot.

I suggest removing that dkms package completely and switch to a HWE kernel that does support your wireless adapter.

First boot with the previous kernel using grub menu. Wi-Fi should work.

Then run in a terminal

```
sudo apt purge 'oem-wifi-intel.*'
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Reboot.

Comment: I just ran commands you gave and everything worked as charm. You are a magician, thank you!

Comment: If you have an ethernet cable, you should be able to just plug in and run these commands instead of using grub menu to boot into previous kernel.

Comment: I had to adapt it for matching the current Ubuntu release (currently 18.04), but it does work! Thanks. Here is a generic command to install it: `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-$(lsb_release -r | cut -f2)`