# Last update does not allow to connect to wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel, iwlwifi

First time post. Basically after an wifi firmware update my laptop doesn't have WiFi anymore.

When I go to "Software & Updates" >> "Additional Drivers" it says device is not working with two options (which before i remember having about 4 options for this device)
-"Do not use device" which is enabled
-"Using oem-wifi-intel-iwlwifi-lp1757035-4.4-dkms driver in DKMS format wrapped by dkms-helper...(open source) When I try to select this it fails.

Dell precision 5520 
Ubuntu 16.04
intel 8265/8275

Verified iwlwifi-8265-XX.ucode is located in /lib/firmware

rfkill list all > no soft or hard blocks on wifi, but soft block on bluetooth.

iwconfig > lo no wireless extensions

Please let me know what other information you need. Thanks!

Comment: Please add output of `uname -r` to the question. If it is `4.4.0-143-generic`, then try to reboot with 4.4.0-142-generic (or any other previous working version).

Comment: Run this command in terminal and post URL from termbin `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: Maybe it's answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126705/no-more-wifi-oem-wifi-intel-iwlwifi-doesnt-build-on-the-new-4-4-kernel