# Dell Precision 7520 laptop with preinstalled Ubuntu 16.04. Software Update failed on a wifi update and broke it

Tags: 16.04, wireless, updates, dell, intel

On March 16, 2019 I ran the software update checker and told it to install all updates. (Up-to-date as of the previous week if not later.)

One update, for wifi, failed.  I did not log its name because I assumed Ubuntu would roll back the changes.  Wrong.  On reboot WiFi wasn’t working.

The laptop has an Ethernet port so it is running online.  Running the software update returns with no updates needed.

I’ve gone online and found many Ubuntu wifi trouble shooting guides but each one I’ve tried has run into problems after the first few steps.

The PCI WiFi is Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78).   On the Intel site they have iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz but its for kernel 4.6 not 4.4.  (uname -r returns “Kernel: 4.4.0-143-generic”)  Its latest update was March 5th which probably lead to the problem on the 16th.

Under **Software & Updates >
Additional drivers**

> Intel Corporation:  Unknown
>   This device is using an alternative driver
>   (selected)
>   using oem-wifi-intel-iwlwifi-lp1757035-4.4-dkms driver in DKMS format wrapped by dkms-helper, from  oem-wifi-intel-iwlwifi-lp1757035-4.4-dkms-dkms (open source)

Only other option is *Do not use*

I selected *Do not use* and the first time it took 5 minutes, the second over 20 minutes and wasn’t finished so I rebooted and it was selected.  Selecting the oem driver took maybe 2 seconds but didn't fix the problem.

`lshw -C network` shows the wireless and ethernet adapters. Wireless is recognized properly as Intel

In `lspci -v`wireless is listed as intel 8265 / 8275 rev 78

In `lshw – C netowrk` wireless configuration line only has `latency=0` (no mention of driver)

```
$ sudo lspci
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)

$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               16384  0
isofs                  40960  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            73728  1 uas
nvram                  16384  0
msr                    16384  0
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
joydev                 20480  0
hid_alps               16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
dell_wmi               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
dell_rbtn              16384  0
dell_led               16384  1
dell_laptop            20480  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             520192  9 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,btintel
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             176128  0
kvm                   552960  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
mei_me                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
idma64                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              16384  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
intel_lpss_pci         16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
shpchp                 36864  0
dell_smo8800           16384  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
intel_hid              16384  0
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_hid
int3402_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  3 int3402_thermal,processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_pad               24576  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                 987136  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              102400  1 btrfs
hid_logitech_hidpp     20480  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 53248  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915_bpo             1343488  7
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
psmouse               131072  0
e1000e                241664  0
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915_bpo
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   40960  3
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
drm                   364544  8 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   122880  6 i2c_hid,hid_alps,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
fjes                   28672  0
```

I couldn’t tell if the correct module was loaded or not but nothing looked like a WiFi module to me.

I do have a full user data backup and the original factory image so I can restore the image if necessary but will lose all the programs installed except Ubuntu and all the tweaks to the interface.

From what I’ve read Ubuntu will detect the hardware and install the appropriate software except maybe not with these Dell / Intel / Ubuntu drivers.  Except there was an updated driver coming though the software update channel.

I don’t know where to go from here.  Can I get the driver through Ubuntu or do I have to restore the factory image?

I did submit a report about the error using the error reporting tool but couldn’t find a local copy.   It it stored somewhere local?

Thank you for your help.

wifi info script output

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Mar 2019 16:43 EDT -0400

Booted last: 21 Mar 2019 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-143-generic #169-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 07:56:38 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, acpi_rev_override, alx.enable_wol=1, mem_sleep_default=deep, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM [8086:15e3] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM [1028:07b0]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0050]

02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5832 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_laptop            20480  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,dell_wmi,dell_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.1.230/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 86246sec preferred_lft 86246sec
    inet6 2601:982:c100:bf10:3884:d08c:764e:9aee/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 594sec preferred_lft 594sec
    inet6 2601:982:c100:bf10:287a:d1a4:2b51:286e/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 594sec preferred_lft 594sec
    inet6 fe80::754c:ec08:f9c2:6a82/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.230  metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1168     1  0 Mar18 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.1-3
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       bad1b2a1-db56-30fc-b668-75b636a1377a
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   bad1b2a1-db56-30fc-b668-75b636a1377a | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.230/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.67.222.222
IP4.DNS[2]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 208.67.222.222 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.230
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       wpad = a
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1553287280
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       host_name = jennifer-Precision-7520
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2601:982:c100:bf10:3884:d08c:764e:9aee/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2601:982:c100:bf10:287a:d1a4:2b51:286e/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::754c:ec08:f9c2:6a82/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::fa32:e4ff:feb8:3fc
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2601:982:c100:bf10::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2601:982:c100:bf10::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:f8:32:e4:b8:3:f8
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_info_refresh_time = 600
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:5b:b9:7a:c:6c:6b:eb:3f:7d:dc:ec:f1:7a:dc:84:14

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Babylon]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Babylon | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Babylon
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730
 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 6773.357055] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 6776.194058] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[ 6776.194132] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s31f6: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: kernel 4.4.0-143 breaks a dkms module.  You can either do what is in the answer @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126705/no-more-wifi-after-uninstalling-codeblocks or install Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, following your instructions I used the purge and install commands.

The wireless worked fine after rebooting.

Not upgrading to 18.04 yet, the user spent the last year learning 16.04 and doesn't want all the new learning experiences with 18.04 (mostly the UI changes).

I have a desktop set up with 18.04 so I can learn it first, making the future upgrade easier.

Next question: How do I mark my question as “solved” with your response.  I can’t find anything on the web page to do so.

Luke

Comment: Luke, we will just mark it as a duplicate of the other question

Comment: Hello Podesta, 

I’m currently migrating the family from Windows 7 to Linux and my priority is to figure out how to run the two Windows programs that either don’t have a Linux version or transferring the data would be a major task.

Until that’s done I don’t want to spend the time learning how to modify the base system as you suggest.

Thank you for you advice,

Luke